# Describing Sets $C_5 ∩ C_8$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to describe the set $C_5 ∩ C_8$, where $c_n = \{nm \mid m ∈ ℤ^+\}$. I can't figure it out as the possibilities of $ℤ^+$ are infinite, I'm guessing set builder is required?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$C_5 = \{5m, m \in \mathbb Z^+\}$$
$$C_8 = \{8m', m' \in \mathbb Z^+\}$$

If $x \in C_5 \cap C_8$, then $x = 5m$ and $x = 8m'$ at the same time ($m, m'\in \mathbb Z^+$), so...

Answer (score 0):

HINT: What are some numbers you can think of which are in both $C_5$ and $C_8$? For example, $10$ is *not* (since $10\not\in C_8$), but $80$ *is* (do you see why?). Do you see a pattern to these numbers?

Answer (score 0):

$a\mathbb{Z}\cap b\mathbb{Z} = lcm(a,b)\mathbb{Z}$